# String_split into table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split

I have a stored procedure which takes two parameters.

- Parameter #1: `StudentID` (int) (e.g. 4, 7, ...)
- Parameter #2: Books to lendIds (string) (contains IDs (int) separated by a semicolon, which books should be lent) like 3;45;83;37.

Now I have a table with two columns:

```
StudentID (Int) | BookID (Int)
```

I want the procedure to separate the IDs in the second parameter with `STRING_SPLIT ( @parameter2 , ';')` and then insert them into the table and write the `studentID` in front of each.

Example:

```
@Parameter1 = 4
@parameter2 = 3;45;83;37
```

This should result as data in the table as follows:

```
StudentID (Int) | BookID (Int)
----------------+----------------
      4         |       3
      4         |      45
      4         |      83
      4         |      37
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to make this work. Can you please help me or give me tips or keywords what I could look for to find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `STRING_SPLIT` as follows:

```sql
SELECT @parameter1 AS StudentID, value AS BookID
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@parameter2, ';');
```

Comment: *and then insert them into the table and write the studentID in front of each*